# MySQL resultset contains 1 row but calling getstring causes Access Violation

Tags: c++, mysql

I am currently learning C++ and slowly making progress but getting an issue with MySQL selects and prepared statements.

I have an app which links to a library and the app is calling the library function as follows:

```
try
        {
            DynamicConfig dynamicConfig;
            string value = "";
            dynamicConfig.getValueFromDBConfig("Test Group", "TestName", &value);
            stringstream logStream;
            logStream << "Dynamic Config Value: " << value;
            bitsLibrary.writeToLog(logStream.str());
        }
        catch (sql::SQLException ex)
        {
            cout << "SQL Exception: " << ex.what() << endl;
        }
        catch (exception ex)
        {
            cout << "General Exception: " << ex.what() << endl;
        }
```

In the library in the DynamicConfig class I have the method getValueFromDBConfig which contains the following:

```
bool DynamicConfig::getValueFromDBConfig(string groupName, string sectionName, string *value)
{
    //Connection *conn = NULL;
    PreparedStatement *statement = NULL;
    ResultSet *resultset = NULL;
    try
    {
        DBManager dbManager;
        Connection *conn = dbManager.getDriverConnection();
        statement = conn->prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM config_items, config_groups WHERE config_groups.Name=? AND config_items.Name=? AND config_groups.id = config_items.ConfigGroupID");
        statement->setString(1, groupName.c_str());
        statement->setString(2, sectionName.c_str());
        resultset = statement->executeQuery();
        cout << "Found " << resultset->rowsCount() << " rows" << endl;
        if (resultset->rowsCount() > 0)
        {

            while (resultset->next())
            {
                cout << "Value: " << resultset->getString("Value") << endl;
                *value = resultset->getString("Value");
            }
            delete conn;
            delete statement;
            delete resultset;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            bitsLibrary.writeToLog("No rows were returned", "DynamicConfig", "getValueFromDBConfig");
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        stringstream logStream;
        logStream << "Failed to get DB config value. SQL Exception: " << ex.what();
        bitsLibrary.writeToLog(logStream.str(), "DynamicConfig", "getValueFromDBConfig");
        throw ex;
    }
    catch (exception ex)
    {
        stringstream logStream;
        logStream << "Failed to get DB config value. General Exception: " << ex.what();
        bitsLibrary.writeToLog(logStream.str(), "DynamicConfig", "getValueFromDBConfig");
        throw ex;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It seems to be successfully executing the query as it prints out `1 rows` to the console however, when I call `resultset->getstring("Value")` it throws an error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF7E831EBA (msvcp140d.dll) in TestApp.exe 0xC0000005. Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFF.
```

I don't understand why this isn't working, its got a row, and the database table I am looking at definitely has the column called Value.

Comment: value is initialised to empty string and passed to the method as a pointer. The value in the DB is `Hello Value`. I know about the exception, I did have it cleaning in the exception handler as well, but took it out in case that was causing the issue

Comment: I've managed to find the answer, I've added an answer, really don't get why that fixes it though, the MySQL example doesn't do what I've had to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out in the end. I need to run getstring as follows

```
*value = resultset->getString("Value").c_str()
```

I don't understand why I need to do this, the MySQL example code I used from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-results.html doesn't show this, so if someone can shed some light on this, that would be great.